# Sitecore 8 - 404 error when changing language in experience editor

Tags: security, sitecore, page-editor, sitecore8

I have set up a new role in my Sitecore 8 (update 3) instance and have assigned the following roles to it (as well as giving read/write access to my content tree):

```
sitecore\Sitecore Client Translating
sitecore\Sitecore Client Users
sitecore\Sitecore Client Authoring
sitecore\Sitecore Client Designing
```

When logged in and using the Content Editor, I can change language ok. When I change language in the <s>Page Editor</s> Experience Editor however, (using Experience > Language menu item) I get a 404 error. If I clear the URL in the browser to the root (hostname) the language appears to have been changed.

**Edit: Additional Information**

It's worth noting that:

1. The solution does not use translated items. We have a separate content tree (within a single instance) for each site/language.
2. The linkManager is configured to use DisplayName for the URL.

Comment: When you change language in the Experience Editor, are you on a page that does not have a version in the selected language?

Comment: Yes, it had versions in en and fr.
I deleted en version and can get to the page ok in either language and can switch language using sc_lang=en or sc_lang=fr request parameter.

Comment: Did you upgrade from a previous version? Any errors in the browser console? Did you try doing a hard refresh in case something is being cached?

Comment: The solution was upgraded from an earlier version of Sitecore 8 (update 2) but that was some time ago. I've tried doing a hard refresh and that did not fix the issue.

Comment: Is the default language French?

Comment: @MatthewDresser When you are in the experience editor, is the URL in format `?sc_item={GUID}&sc_lang=fr` or is it the normal URL generated by the LinkManager?

Answer (score 0):

Please share the snapshot of your new content tree structure and link manager config settings if possible. Meanwhile, can you please revert link manager settings and check if it works fine? Also use firebug net tab with persist to see the URLs requested while click on second language.

Also, please check following cookies values if updated your-site-name#lang:-
website#lang

here webiste is name of default sitecore site

Moreover, when your Experience Editor is loaded, just to make sure, click on default language from language menu to see if it works even for default language.

As said keep your firebug open with persist and keep eye on net tab with all to see if any resource request having 404.